# db_query() gives old results

Tags: 6

I've this query

```
$results = db_query("SELECT * from irctc_qc   order by updated desc limit 400");
```

I've even tried this:

```
$time = time(NULL);
 $results = db_query("SELECT * from irctc_qc  where $time>1   order by updated desc limit 400");
```

But I find it is not showing latest data. Latest rows show late by around 20 minutes.

I searched everywhere but could not find the reason.

`mysqli_query` giving correct results.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you running any query caching?

Comment: No nothing. First time I'm ever seeing this. I've aware of query caching only in Views though

Comment: How are you verifying the data? Are you inspecting `$results` as the query is run, or just the page containing the rendered output?

Comment: @Clive Yes dumping $results in a file.

Comment: Seeing the full code of the function running that query would help. knowing if that is a page callback function would help too.

Comment: Also, in the second query, `where $time > 1` isn't altering the executed query. It's just a condition that is surely true (except in the case the server thinks it's midnight of January 1, 1970).

Comment: But query won't be cached as $time is different every time

Comment: `db_query()` doesn't cache the query result. Eventually, Drupal caches the page output, but in that case putting `where $time > 1` in the query won't help, if the page output doesn't change.

Comment: That's why I said that seeing the full code of the function running that query and knowing if that function is a page callback would help.